# Apache Nifi: Convert a SOAP file into JSON

Tags: json, xml, soap, apache-nifi

I am fairly new to Apache Nifi. 
I am trying to convert a SOAP file into JSON. Is there an easy way to do that or is there a tutorial that can teach me?
By SOAP file I mean an xml file used in SOAP web service.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NiFi has some general-purpose XML handling processors, including [EvaluateXPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXPath/index.html) for particular values, and [TransformXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) for full XSL transforms.  There is no generic XML -> JSON transform (yet).

I recommend TransformXml only if you need all of the data in a complex document, or if you are experienced with XSLT.  Building and testing an XSLT stylesheet can be tough.

For simpler data or less than the full document, you will find it easier to use EvaluateXPath to get data elements into NiFi flow file attributes, then format those attributes into JSON with [AttributesToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/index.html).

Comment: It is failing because of the HTTP headers. Is there a smart way to get ride of the first lines?

Comment: Another option is ExecuteScript using Groovy and its XmlSlurper and JsonBuilder classes to do the transformation.